# Proving $\|f\|_{\infty}$ Is A Norm

Tags: calculus, normed-spaces

> Let $V=C[a,b]$. For $f\in V$ define
>   $$
> \|f\|_{\infty}=\max\{|f(x)|:a\leq x\leq b\}
> $$

How can we prove the triangle inequality property of a norm?

$$\begin{align}\|f+g\|_{\infty}&{\leq} \max\{|f(x)|+|g(x)|:a\leq x\leq b\}\\
&\stackrel{(?)}{\leq} \max\{|f(x)|:a\leq x\leq b\}+\max\{|g(x)|:a\leq x\leq b\} \\
&=\|f\|_{\infty}+\|g\|_{\infty}\end{align}$$

The relation I found is:

$$|f(x)|\leq max\{|f(x)|\}$$

$$|g(x)|\leq max\{|g(x)|\}$$

So: $$|f(x)|+|g(x)|\leq max\{|f(x)|\}+max\{|g(x)|\}$$

And:

$$max\{|f(x)|+|g(x)|\}\leq max\{max\{|f(x)|\}+max\{|g(x)|\}\}\neq max\{|f(x)|\}+max\{|g(x)|\}$$

Comment: Of course $\max\{\max\{|f(x)|\}+\max\{|g(x)|\}\}=\max\{|f(x)|\}+\max\{|g(x)|\}$. If you look carefully, $\max\{\lvert f(x)\rvert\}$ is a number, not a function, so it's like saying $\max\{9+27\}=9+27$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $f$ and $g$, $\|f\|_\infty$ and $\|g\|_\infty$ are fixed positive numbers.

Now let $x \in [a,b]$. Then $|f(x)| \le \|f\|_\infty$ by definition, and also
$|g(x)| \le \|g\|_\infty$ by definition.

But then $$|(f + g)(x)  =|f(x) + g(x)| \le |f(x) + g(x)| \le \|f\|_\infty + \|g\|_\infty$$

the right hand side is a *fixed* real number that is an upperbound for *all* numbers of the form $|(f+g)(x)|$ so $$\|f+g\|_\infty = \max\{|(f+g)(x)|: x \in [a,b]\} \le \|f\|_\infty + \|g\|_\infty$$

Answer (score 2):

By a triangle inequality $|f(x)+g(x)|\le |f(x)|+|g(x)|\le\|f\|_{\infty}+\|g\|_{\infty}$. Now take the supremum on the left hand side.

Comment: $$max\{|f(x)+g(x)\} \leq max\{||f||_{\infty}+||g||_{\infty}\}?$$

Comment: @gbox you're taking the max of 1 number on the right hand side!

Answer (score 1):

I find easier this way:

There are points $m_f,m_g\in[a,b]$ such that $\|f\|_\infty=|f(m_f)|$ and $\|g\|_\infty=|g(m_g)|$. Then, for any $x\in[a,b]$,
$$|f(x)+g(x)|\le |f(x)|+|g(x)|\le |f(m_f)|+|g(m_g)|=\|f\|_\infty+\|g\|_\infty$$

Comment: I understand the proof, I just can not see where we have shown that $max\{|f(x)+g(x)|\}\le ||f||_{\infty}+||g||_{\infty}$

Comment: Since the inequality above holds for any $x$, then we can take the maximum on the left.